# internal link in automatic MSOutlook-reply?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, links, out-of-office

In MSOutlook's automatic reply I have out-of-office text in 4 languages.

Is there a way to have this look like this:

> NL / EN / FR / DE
>
> Text in NL-language blabla..
>
> Text in EN-language .. 
>   etc.

Where "EN" is a clickable link to "Text in EN-language"?

Answer (score 0):

With the build-in OOF text editor, it's not possible to add a link to a text. You may consider to use the OOF rule with a template. Follow these steps:

1. In the OOF setup Window, click **Rules...** button in the left
   bottom corner.
2. Click **Add Rules** button.
3. Tick the checkbox before "Reply with", and click **Template** button next to it.
4. Type the all the text you want in the opened email template.
5. First, we need to add bookmarks to each language version of OOF text. To do this, select each text with different language version, click **Insert** tab, click **Bookmark** button from the ribbon. Name the bookmark and click **Add**. Do this for each language.
   [image]
6. Now, insert a hyperlink to the text 'NL', 'EN', etc. and browse to the bookmarks you just created. To do this, select the text you want to insert a link to, right click on the text and click **Link**. Select the corresponding bookmark and click **OK** button. Create a link for each language version.
   [image]
7. Click the link you created to verify whether it works.

Comment: By "all the text" you mean eg "Text in NL-language blabla..", correct? Adding the bookmark is done _inside_ the opened template, right? Then I close the template and it asks if I want to save, and I say _yes_, right? Repeat procedure for EN and click _OK_ When looking in the oof-text, it is the same text that was there before - I don't see any changes - no rules, bookmarks.. Sorry but I don't understand your outlines too well I guess.

Comment: Out of office message was in German only, after trying to follow the above steps - so I had to delete all the rules. Could you please clarify how to do it correctly?